# How can I use websockets with Redux-Bees

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux

Instead of getting data from a `http` via `Rest` api. I am getting data from a `websocket` in my `react` application. I want to use `Redux-bees` to just get the `realtime` data from the `websokcet`.

Is this possible?